# How to get item's id and change it with javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, database

I have a simple form in `C# asp.net` that has some defined id's.

I've created a simple `JavaScript` code, which on click opens new - same form.

Now the problem is when you try to insert all the data into database...because when it opens same form, id's stay the same...

```
<asp:TextBox ID="input_text" class="form-control" runat="server">   </asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="input_num" type="number" class="form-control" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="input_dropdown" class="form-control" runat="server">
<asp:ListItem Text="" Value=""></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Material1" Value="Material1"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Material2" Value="Material2"></asp:ListItem>
<asp:ListItem Text="Material3" Value="Material3"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList><br />
<asp:FileUpload ID="fileUpload" runat="server" class="form-control"   onchange="readURL(this)" /><br />
<asp:Image ID="fileUploadImg" class="form-control" runat="server" Height="300px" /><br />
```

How can I get those id's in JavaScript and change them for a number or something. Just so it will work with database.

**Example:**

First textbox has id of input_text

When I'd click on new form, the first form should have id of input_text, but the second should have like input_text1 or something.

**Javascript to load new form**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){+
    $("#btnAddNewProduct").click(function () {
        $(".form-group").after($(".form-group").html());
    });
});
```

**what i've tried**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){+
    $("#btnAddNewProduct").click(function () {
        var prvi = document.getElementsByTagName("asp:TextBox");
        for (var i = 0; i < prvi.length; i++)
        {
            //some code - dunno what to do
        }
        $(".form-group").after($(".form-group").html());
    });
});
```

Any ideas?

Thank you!

**UPDATE**

```
script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#btn-dodaj").click(function () {
    var dodaj = "<br/><div class=\"forma\">" +
        "<div class=\"forma1\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"vnesi..\"/><br/></div>" +
        "<div class=\"forma2\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"vnesi..\"/><br/></div>" +
        "<div class=\"forma3\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"vnesi..\"/><br/></div>" +
        "<div class=\"forma4\"><input type=\"text\" class=\"form-control\" placeholder=\"vnesi..\"/></div>" +
        "</div>";
            $(".form-group").append(dodaj);
        });
});
```

Comment: You should not create clone for that

Comment: why not @Jigar7521

Comment: You are coping same form on click, so it means ids will be duplicates

Comment: well...yes...that's why i'm asking how to change it @Jigar7521